# connecting pyqt4 signals in a pyqt4 qobject class

Tags: python, signals, pyqt4, slot

I've got two classes; one for my window and one for my controlling object

```
class window(baseClass, testForm):
    scanStarted = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        #other window setup
        self._scanner.pushScan.clicked.connect(self._scanClicked)

    def _scanClicked(self):
        self.scanStarted.emit( self._scanner.getTextData() )
```

and my controlling object

```
class vis(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        self._oreList = []

        self._w = window()
        self._w.scanStarted.connect(self._scanOre)

    def _scanOre(self, rawText):
        print "main ->", rawText
```

When using the QtCore.QObject as my reference, this signal won't connect to the _scanOre. When I switch the reference to python 'object' it'll work fine. I've been trying to figure out why it won't connect using the QtCore.QObject type.

The signal will also connect just fine in the window class regardless.

I tried giving the _scanOre the @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str, name='scanGo') and adding the name parameter into the signal creation as well. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to initialize the `QObject`:

```
class vis(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(vis, self).__init__(parent) # you are missing this line
                                          # also the `parent` arg
        self._oreList = []

        self._w = window.window()
        self._w.scanStarted.connect(self._scanOre)

    def _scanOre(self, rawText):
        print "main ->", rawText
```

Comment: Oh man, I knew it was going to be something easy I was overlooking.