# PyQt QTextEdit: Detect change Event

Tags: python, qt, events, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm **overwriting some events** in PyQT QTextEdit, for example:

```
class myTextEditor(QTextEdit):
    def keyPressEvent(self,e):
                print 'key pressed'
        return super(myTextEditor, self).keyPressEvent(e)
```

Howewer, the **changeEvent**, [documented here](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/platform-api-reference/xml/daily-docs/libqt4/qtextedit.html#changeEvent), doesn't seem to work. Here's my code

```
def changeEvent(self,e):
    print 'change'
    return super(myTextEditor, self).changeEvent(e)
```

There's no error but the event isn't processed.

Any ideas how to use a **changeEvent** (when the text is changed) in PyQt for a QTextEdit ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`changeEvent` is not related to changing text edit's content. It addresses only general QWidget state changes. See [this page](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/platform-api-reference/xml/daily-docs/libqt4/qwidget.html#changeEvent) to get the list of events related to this method.

You should connect to the `QTextEdit::textChanged()` signal to track text changes.

Comment: Here's what I tried:   `self.textChanged.triggered.connect(self.changeText)`. I get the following: `pyqtsignal must be bound to a Qobject, not mytexteditor`

Comment: Try to remove `.triggered`. It definitely shouldn't be there.

Comment: May be `self` is not a proper `QObject`. See an example in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12694586/344347).

Comment: Indeed I forgot to do `super(myTextEditor, self).__init__(parent)` bbefore the connecting. Thanks !!

Comment: What works is self.textEdit.textChanged.connect(self.doSomething)

Comment: The link is dead